# SELECT from multiple Tables and String

Tags: mysql, arrays, string, count, expressionengine

I'm trying to get the 'total results' of a query, but kind of struggling to get my head around it and just keep encountering errors. This is my table setup:

```
exp_channel_data table
entry_id   field_id_17
36         1
43         6
42         5
65         7

exp_freeform_form_entries_2 table
form_field_8    user_id
40              6
35              1
38              1


exp_matrix_data table
entry_id   col_id_20
36         [35] [test-course] Test Course
36         [38] [test-course-2] Test Course 2
43         [40] [health-safety] Health & Safety
43         [35] [test-course] Test Course
43         [38] [test-course-2] Test Course 2
65         [40] [health-safety] Health & Safety
```

I need to do a Query that checks to see if a "Course" `(col_id_20)` inside `exp_matrix_data` exists as a "Completed Course" `(form_field_8)` inside `exp_free_form_entries_2` (Linked with the number between the []). I then need to output a "Count" of "Uncompleted Courses"

Because multiple "Members" can take Courses, I need to check "Courses" from the logged in User.

Each User is stored in the `exp_channel_data` as two different ID's - "User Profile ID" `(entry_id)` where the "Courses" are assigned to the User, and also a "Unique Member ID" `(field_id_17)`.

The "User Profile ID" I will input dynamically, which I normally do with:

```
WHERE entry_id = '{logged_in_id}'
```

So if I was to run a Query to see if "Unique Member ID" `(field_id_17)` of value `6` which has a "User Profile ID" of `43` had any completed "Uncompleted Courses" it would result in `2` "Uncompleted Courses" because only `1` Course was completed:

```
43 [40] [health-safety] Health & Safety
```

## Relationships

entry_id [exp_channel_data] => entry_id [exp_matrix_data]

field_id_17 [exp_matrix_data] => user_id [exp_freeform_form_entries_2]

col_id_20 [exp_matrix_data] => form_field_8 [exp_freeform_form_entries_2]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the specs you gave I expect this query to bring you closer to what you want:

```
select d.* 
from exp_channel_data ch 
inner join exp_freeform_form_entries_2 ff 
  on ch.field_id_17 = ff.user_id
inner join exp_matrix_data d 
  on d.col_id_20 like Concat('[', ff.form_field_8, ']%')
where ch.entry_id = 36
```

check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fbaa4/4)

Comment: I've amended the question slighty because I realised that the rows inside 'exp_freeform_form_entries_2' need to also be limited to ID number

Comment: Sorry, it is confusing but this is running through a CMS that sets these col names. I need to confirm the entry_id in exp_matrix_data but the entry_id now has to relate to the field_id_17 col, which is also user_id

Comment: You have to indicate which tables/columns relate to each other and how you reaon that your outcome only has two rows...

Comment: I've updated the question with a better description and relationships between columns and tables

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
select count(*) from exp_matrix_data where entry_id = '{logged_in_id}' and
 CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(col_id_20, 2),']',1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) NOT IN (SELECT     form_field_8 FROM exp_freeform_form_entries_2 where user_id in (select distinct(ecd.field_id_17) from exp_channel_data ecd where ecd.entry_id = '{logged_in_id}'))
```

Comment: This returns '1' when it should return '2'

Comment: Your question is now confusing to me, after you edited it. May be reframe it to explain more clearly?

Comment: I've updated the question with a better description and relationships between columns and tables